# Can't install mono

Tags: apt, package-management, debian, mono

I'm currently stuck and cannot install mono-devel on my PC. I've installed the mono keyring and repo, but whenever I try to install it I get this:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: mono-runtime (>= 3.0~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6 (>= 2.31) but 2.28-10 is to be installed or
                       libc6.1 (>= 2.31) but it is not installable or
                       libc0.1 (>= 2.31) but it is not installable
              Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.64.6) but 2.58.3-2+deb10u2 is to be installed
              Depends: libmono-cecil-private-cil (>= 6.12.0.122) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-cecil-private-cil (< 6.12.0.123) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-codecontracts4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-compilerservices-symbolwriter4.0-cil (>= 3.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-peapi4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.8) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-relaxng4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-security4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-configuration-install4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-core4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-data4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-io-compression-filesystem4.0-cil (>= 3.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-runtime-serialization4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-security4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-xml-linq4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-xml4.0-cil (>= 3.12.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: mono-mcs (= 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu2004b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: mono-roslyn (= 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu2004b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: mono-gac (= 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu2004b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: mono-xbuild (= 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu2004b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu2004b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-2.0-dev (>= 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu2004b1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-2.0-dev (< 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu2004b1.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: ca-certificates-mono (= 6.12.0.122-0xamarin1+ubuntu2004b1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Please help, thank you all.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the version that is built for your system not the latest one available. You have a 20.04 system trying to install packages built for at least the 20.10 going from the libc6 error. When you add a repository to your install they need to be of the same release or they will never install.

Comment: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/